# Excel Interop: success of OpenXML() depends on filename

Tags: excel, excel-interop

I have two empty *Excel* files, named `error_1.xlsx` and `error_3.xlsx`. `comp.exe` shows them byte-for-byte identical. Nevertheless, while opening them with [`.OpenXML()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.openxml), `error_3.xlsx` opens successfully, but `error_1.xlsx` causes `.OpenXML()` to fail with `HRESULT 0x800a03ec`. By experimenting with changing file contents and names I have proven that the result of `.OpenXML()` depends solely on filename. I access *Excel* via the *COM* interop interface from the server-side of an enterprise system, running from a non-interactive user account.

I have not been able to reproduce this error while invoking `.OpenXML()` from a test *C#* program from my own Windows session, which means that it is connected with the user-specific context. Since I have no idea how to reproduce the problem outside my environment, I can only demonstrate it via some kind of screen-sharing session (should you be so kind).

I conjectured the problem could be in some cache and temp files, but tracing filesystem events from `excel.exe` with [*Process monitor*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon)  did not help.